# Kdiff do not load files after merge conflicts

Tags: git-extensions, kdiff3

After doing the git extension update, stopped loading files while resolving conflicts I get an empty window where there are no files in the base, local and remote version(but files are created in folder with *.base, *.local, *.remote extensions).

After click Open in KDiff I see:

[image]

I`m using versions:

Git extension - 3.3
Kdiff - 0.9.98

Answer (score 1):

Software bugs should be reported to app developers, no point raising bugs or asking about them here.
There is a "Report an issue" menu under "Help":

[image]

As far as your issue is concerned, please see https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/7544 and https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/7549

Comment: At that time he probably thought that he did something wrong or didn't do something, didn't know if it was a bug. The 3.3.1 release from 2 days ago fixes this issue.